LLM - Add n-shot prompting in dify (pdf)
I'm using Dify and would like to improve my workflow by adding a One-shot prompting.
The workflow is very simple:


Upload file (pdf)
Extract data from pdf -> output "text"
Send output "text" to the Ollama model & Ask questions (extract invoice ID, customer reference etc..)
Return JSON.

For the moment, it is OK and the result is as expected but I would like to take into the context of a sample file IN and sample Output JSON.
I have tried to add 2 variables in the first step (sample file & output sample file) but I obtained an issue (file required [even after I upload it], or error "type unknown").
Is my idea correct?
Does somebody have an idea how to manage it?
Thanks!
